# Can we access the container from boost variant?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, containers, boost-variant

How do we know which container data is present in boost variant? My variant is having any datatype or container. how to access the type of the data from the container?

```
boost::variant<string, int> myvar = 245;
if(myvar.type() == typeid(int)){
    std::cout<<"integer data type"<< '\n';//I am able to get the type of integer/string
}

boost::variant<vector<int>, list<string>> v {1,2,3,4};//???
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I doubt it will compile.

Comment: boost::variant<vector<int>, list<string>>v=std::vector<int> {1,2,3,4};//this is compiling..

Answer (score 2):

There are mainly 2 ways for you to access the underlying element of a `variant`:

- A compile-time type safe value visitation with `apply_visitor`
- A run-time checked explicit value retrieval with `get<T>`

---

To use `apply_visitor`, you would first create a visitor functor by inherit from `boost::static_visitor<T>`, where `T` is the return type of the visitor:

```cpp
struct my_visitor : boost::static_visitor<size_t>
{
    size_t operator()(std::vector<int> vec) const
    {
        for(int i : vec) std::cout << i << ',';
        return vec.size();
    }

    size_t operator()(std::list<std::string> list) const
    {
        for(std::string s : list) std::cout << s << ',';
        return list.size();
    }
};
```

Here both version of the visitor well print out the entire container, and return the size of the container. Notice the parameter type would correspond to the each types included with the variant. Then you can apply the visitor to the variant with:

```cpp
size_t size = boost::apply_visitor(my_visitor(), v);
```

Also, since the two paths of the visitor behave almost the same, you can also just write a single template function:

```cpp
struct my_visitor : boost::static_visitor<std::size_t>
{
    template<typename Container>
    std::size_t operator()(Container cont) const
    {
        for(auto s : cont) std::cout << s << ',';
        return cont.size();
    }
};
```

With C++14 or later, you may also use a lambda instead of a functor:

```cpp
size_t size = apply_visitor(
    [](auto cont){ 
        for(auto s : cont) std::cout << s << ',';
        return cont.size();
    }, v
);
```

---

The other way is to rely on run-time check:

```cpp
auto& vec = boost::get<std::vector<int>>(v);
```

Now `vec` would be a `std::vector<int>&`. If the contained type is not a `std::vector<int>`, this will throw a `boost::bad_get`. And if you used a type that's not included in the `variant` you provided, it will be a compile time error.

Comment: the above struct container template is throwing compile time error. what would be the issue with return type ?

Comment: @Sirisha Was it the one with templated `operator()`? My bad, it should have inherited from `static_visitor<std::size_t>`.

Comment: @Sirisha The return type of the `operator()` must be the same as the inheritance of `static_visitor<T>`

Comment: @Sirisha Yes, `cont.size()` returns a `size_t`

Answer (score 0):

`boost::variant<vector<int>, list<string>> v {1,2,3,4};//???`

fails because the compiler can not determine the type from the given initializer list.

You simply can provide the type and all works as expected:

```
boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::list<std::string>> v=std::vector<int> {1,2,3,4};
```

BTW: Why use `boost::variant`? You also have `std::variant` which fits maybe better?

Answering the questions in the comments: see full example below!

```
using vartype = boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::list<std::string>>;
void access( vartype& v )
{
    // this is a very ugly idea, because on every change of the types of your variant, the numbers for the switch are unvalid!
    switch( v.which() )
    {    
        case 0: // first type of variant -> here it is vec<int>
            {
                auto& i = boost::get<std::vector<int>>( v ); 
                for ( auto& el: i ) { std::cout << el << std::endl; }
            }
            break;

        case 1: // second type in variant -> here it is list<string>
            {
                auto& s = boost::get<std::list<std::string>>(v);
                for ( auto& el: s ) { std::cout << el << std::endl; }
            }
            break;

        default:
            ;
    }    
}

// the visit method is much easier and better to maintain
struct MyVisitor: public boost::static_visitor<>
{
    void operator()(std::vector<int>& i) { for ( auto& el: i ) { std::cout << el << std::endl; } }
    void operator()(std::list<std::string>& s) { for ( auto& el: s ) { std::cout << el << std::endl; } }
};


int main()
{
    vartype vint = std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4};
    vartype vstring = std::list<std::string>{"This","is","easy"};

    access( vint );
    access( vstring );

    // or with visitor:
    MyVisitor vis;
    boost::apply_visitor( vis, vint );
    boost::apply_visitor( vis, vstring );

    // if you go with STL
    using stltype = std::variant< std::vector<int>, std::list<std::string>>;

    stltype si = std::vector<int>{ 5,4,3,2,1 };
    stltype ss = std::list<std::string>{"That","is","easier"};

    auto lambda = [](auto&& vec){ for ( auto& el: vec ) { std::cout << el << std::endl; }};

    std::visit( lambda, si );
    std::visit( lambda, ss );
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/x443W6afh)

Comment: thanks, std::variant is made available from c++17. I need to use c++11.

Comment: my doubt is, how to access the vector<int> elements  from boost variant

Comment: Can you explain reasons why `std::variant` fits better, @Klaus?

Comment: @sehe: from my point of view the STL variant is more elaborated and easier to use. And even the documentation is better readable ( for me ).

Comment: @Sirisha: Full example added... now you should take some time to read the documentation...

Comment: @Klaus as a counter point, I'd like you to show me recursive variants in C++, or one with a never-empty guarantee :) They're just different IMO. There are valid reasons to prefer Boost Variant. Maybe a little less with Boost Variant2 except when <C++17 (Also, where do you find "documentation" for std::variant? I don't think I've found good highlevel usage guides e.g. with error handling included except on personal tech blogs)

Comment: @Sirisha: Do you know how Stackoverflow works? If you want to say thanks, you give an upvote. If the answer fits to your needs, you accept it. If both is true, do both. Thats how we pay in SO. Other readers find it helpful to see the answer which fits best because it was accepted. And if you have another question, don't ask in comment, ask a new question please!